# What model field type should I be using to store a number of type long?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm wanting to store longitude and latitude values using Django's ORM, I've tried using a BigInt type but its cutting off a lot of the decimal places. Should I be using the Decimal type here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the GeoDjango-Docs you should use a `FloatField`.
[=> Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#defining-a-geographic-model)

Comment: Had to wait ten minutes, forgot to come back. Accepted now, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Actually [GeoDjango docs says PointField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/). I worked on a project involving geospatial computations and I was using PointField in the models.

FloatField probably uses floating point representation of the coordinates, which might introduce floating point errors. PointField is initialized with string representation of the lat/long values.

Comment: This answer is equally correct, but I think its slightly overkill for my app.